# Net::XMPP Perl module:ssl path error on windows system

Tags: windows, perl, xmpp

I am trying to connect to an XMPP server using the perl module Net::XMPP on a windows 10 machine running Strawberry Perl and I get the following error:

```
Invalid or unreadable path specified for ssl_ca_path. at C:/strawberry/perl/site/lib/XML/Stream.pm line 640
```

The code I am using is below:

```
#!/bin/perl -w

use strict;
use warnings;

use Net::XMPP;

my $con = new Net::XMPP::Client(); 

my $status = $con->Connect(  
    hostname => 'hostnamepart',  
    connectiontype => 'tcpip',  
    tls => 1);  
die('ERROR: XMPP connection failed') if ! defined($status);
```

I have tested if I can connect to the server using the Pidgin client app on my Windows machine and it works fine.

> Is there any way to fix my Perl problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From what I can tell from a look at the sources, `ssl_ca_path` must be provided when `ssl => 1` or `tls => 1` is used. (It can be a file or directory.)

For example,  believe you can use something like the following to trust the CAs that Mozilla trusts.

```
use Mozilla::CA       qw( );
use Net::XMPP::Client qw( );

my $con = Net::XMPP::Client->new();

$con->Connect(  
    ...
    tls         => 1,
    ssl_ca_path => Mozilla::CA::SSL_ca_file(),
);
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply...Unfortunately that does not fix my problem, I now get the error "ERROR: XMPP connection failed at perlprog.pl line 23"

Comment: Well, it did solve the problem you asked about. It seems you have another one. Error message appears to be in `$con->GetErrorCode()`. (Bad documentation!!!)